# Which event should I listen to in order to get contract instantiation data?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js, evm

I'm trying to index the names and decimals of tokens in moonbeam, I think I should listen for a contract instantiation event to get that data. Which event and module should I listen for? Or is there any other straight forward way to get the data that i'm looking for?

Comment: "names and decimals of tokens in moonbeam" - do you mean total issuance or do you mean you want to understand volume of what tokens are being transacted? (You can see the events related to moonbeam here: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fwss.api.moonbeam.network#/explorer )

Comment: @Squirrel I'm trying to get token name, decimals, such as shown here: https://moonbeam.moonscan.io/token/0x818ec0a7fe18ff94269904fced6ae3dae6d6dc0b#readContract

Answer (score 1):

You should probably listen to `Evm.ContractDeployed` events to track all contracts ever deployed. However, you'd then need to filter ERC20-like contracts among those, which is a non-trivial task to do (but one can try looking at the methods implemented by the contract to "duck-guess").